# What rule is used for this simplification?

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

$$ \frac{8}{(s+1)^2 + 2^2} \times \frac{1}{s} = \frac{8}{5} - \frac{1}{s} + \frac{16}{10}\times \frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2 + 2^2} + \frac{8}{10}\times \frac{2}{(s+1)^2 + 2^2}
 $$

Comment: I think you tagged the question with the correct answer?

Comment: Partial Fraction! :)

Comment: This equality looks wrong to me. A typo somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some partial fraction magic?

$$\frac{8}{s(s^2+2s+5)} = \frac{As+B}{s^2+2s+5} + \frac{C}{s}$$

This gives $C=8/5, A=-8/5, B=-16/5$ I think, so

$$\frac{8}{s(s^2+2s+5)} = \left(\frac{8}{5}\right)\left[\frac{1}{s}-\frac{s+2}{s^2+2s+5}\right].$$

Comment: Thanks, that was the trick, I made an mistake while doing partial fraction :)